# Wireless Card dies minutes after boot, every time

Tags: wireless-networking, internet

starting today ( 3 days after a careful move ) my computer started randomly dropping the internet connection.  I realized the problem seemed to be with the wireless card because when the problem occurs I cant even connect or see a local network.  the wireless card just seems to disappear.  However it still shows up in device manager.

When i boot my computer the wireless works fine but then after 5-20 minutes the problem occurs.  and the only solution ive found so far is restarting my computer.  Ive tried updating the driver through the built in windows driver update (because im lazy) and ive popped out the card and put it back into the motherboard.   the computer and everything in it is less than a year old. Any ideas?

Win 7 ultimate SP 1.

TP-LINK 300Mbps Wireless N Adapter  DRIVER: 8.0.0.376 from 10/23/2010

Comment: What OS? Which wireless card (including chipset, etc)? ***Edit:*** Looks like OS is Windows, but which version?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to determine if it is a software or a hardware issue.

1. manually uninstall the drivers, reinstall, and reboot. (This should solve most driver issues) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725782.aspx
2. Does the wireless network card work in a different pci slot?
3. Does the motherboard LAN networking adapter work?